# Facebook fbrocket api for android

Tags: android, facebook

i want to develop an application that take email and password of facebook as input, and gets the friends list from facebook.

For this i am using fbrocket.jar api. But i can't login into the account of facebook through android mobile. Is this fbrocket.jar api enough or not?. Is there any facebook api .jar for android?

any one can resolv my problem . plz clarify my doubts.

ThanQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Facebook doesn't allow other applications to authenticate to Facebook by using email and password.

Facebook has released a Facebook API which allows 1) your application to be registered in Facebook and 2) through your application, you can get a user Session Key (which is essentially your application authentication for a user's behalf).

FBRocket essentially wrapped the Facebook API to make Facebook RESTful function call easier in Java (for Android).

For full spec on the Facebook API, visit: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API
To know how Facebook Authenticate your application, http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Facebook_Authenticates_Your_Application.

In short, create a Facebook Application, get a Facebook `application ID` and `application secret` (from Facebook) and you're good to go to getting all you want using the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from fbrocket, you can use this [one](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/). You can download it [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/).